# cv2.line will not draw any lines

Tags: python, opencv

I wanted to test out opencv using an image I had. So far, every transformation has worked just fine, but I haven't been able to add a line to any image.

I had a function that would generate an image and then return it but since that returned a black square, I tried to show the image inside the function itself. This was based on a lecture example in class and there's nothing I'm doing that's different from what the lecturer was doing.

My function to create the image:

```
def display_lines(image, lines):
    line_image = np.zeros_like(image)
    if lines is not None:
        for line in lines:
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = line.reshape(4)
            print((x1,y1))
            print((x2,y2))
            cv2.line(line_image, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,255,0), 5)
    cv2.line(line_image, (-91,300), (172,120), (0,255,0), 5)
    cv2.imshow('line_image', line_image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return(line_image)
```

This is where I originally would display the image:

```
averaged_lines = average_slope_intercept(img, lines)
img = display_lines(img, averaged_lines)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Image Size:

```
img = cv2.resize(img, (650, 500))
```

I checked the lines and I'm getting correct points and passing tuples to the line function: (-91, 300) (172, 120) (751, 300) (527, 120)

My impression is that cv2 will crop the lines but still display them if they're too long, so I don't get why they aren't showing up.

Comment: what color and type is the image you are trying to draw in?

Comment: try cv2.line(line_image, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (255,255,255), 5) if your image was single channel black, you were drawing a black linr of black

Comment: I was trying to draw a green line on a black background, but I'll try that.

Comment: is your black background 3 channel or 1 channel image? If you try to draw green on 1 channel it will just be black on black.

Comment: Turns out it was 1 channel. I made it 3 channel and that fixed the issue.